# How to record using jmeter without proxy or through automatic proxy

Tags: jmeter

In my company to access my application to record, i need internet connection (with auto proxy: Ex: http://autoproxy.xx.xx), how and where can i set this proxy in **HTTPS Test script recorder?** thanks,

Comment: I am facing the same issue, unable to use local proxy server because of company policy. it would be great if you could help me in understanding, How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems JMeter doesn't support PAC files. Try an alternative recording solution  i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google search for "JMeter automatic proxy".  The first search result said this:

> PAC fiels[sic] contain javascript which is executed by the browser to decide which proxy URL they want to use. JMeter is not a browser so it does not run this code. The solution is simply to resolve which proxy this script returns and input this value into JMeter directly, you can do this using the dev tools on most browsers, or just ask the IT dept. that maintains the thing to tell you the direct address.